# Display selected data from mysql with Laravel 9 and Vue js 3

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js

I have a vue component that displays data with loop like this :

```
<div class="courses-container" v-for="(value, index) in list_lowongan">
        <div class="course">
          <div class="course-info1">
            <h2 class="lowongan1"> {{ value.title }}</h2>
            <button id="pagiLowongan2" v-on:click="toggleBody(index)"><img src="images/panahkanan.png" class="panah1"></button>
              <p class="descJob1">{{ value.body }}</p>
              <p class="textDesc" v-if="value.showBody">Job Description : </p>
              <ul class="a" id="bulletLowongan" v-if="value.showBody">
                <li class="textDescKecil">{{ value.jobdesc1 }}</li>
                <li class="textDescKecil">{{ value.jobdesc2 }}</li>
                <li class="textDescKecil">{{ value.jobdesc3 }}</li>
                <li class="textDescKecil">{{ value.jobdesc4 }}</li>
                <li class="textDescKecil">{{ value.jobdesc5 }}</li>
              </ul>
              <p class="textDesc" v-if="value.showBody">Requirements : </p>
              <ul class="a" id="bulletLowongan" v-if="value.showBody">
                <li class="textDescKecil">{{ value.req1 }}</li>
                <li class="textDescKecil">{{ value.req2 }}</li>
                <li class="textDescKecil">{{ value.req3 }}</li>
                <li class="textDescKecil">{{ value.req4 }}</li>
              </ul>
              <p class="textDesc" v-if="value.showBody">Work Type : {{ value.worktype }} </p>
              <p class="Locationlow" v-if="value.showBody">Location : {{ value.location }} </p>
              <p class="Locationlow" v-if="value.showBody">Employment Type : {{ value.employmenttype }} </p>
              <router-link to="/apply" class="routesApply" v-if="value.showBody">Apply</router-link>
              <hr class="garisJob1">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Script :

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      'form': {
        title: '',
        body: '',
        jobdesc1: '',
        jobdesc2: '',
        jobdesc3: '',
        jobdesc4: '',
        jobdesc5: '',
        req1: '',
        req2: '',
        req3: '',
        req4: '',
        req5: '',
        worktype: '',
        location: '',
        employmenttype: '',
      },

      list_lowongan: []
    };
  },

    mounted() {
        console.log('on mounted');
        axios.get('post/list').then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data)
            this.list_lowongan = response.data
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        });
    },

    methods: {
      toggleBody(index) {
      this.list_lowongan[index].showBody = !this.list_lowongan[index].showBody;
    }
    }
};
</script>
```

The problem is, this loop displays all the data in the table,
What should I do if I want to display only selected row from the table ?
For example :
The first row in the table is John Doe, and the second is John Doe2, by using this code, It will display both John Doe and John Doe2, but what should I do if I want to display the John Doe2 without the first one being displayed also?

Comment: I am a little bit lost, how do you "filter" which one to display? I see you are getting the list and you are fully showing it, so, what have you tried to prevent display "john doe" when you want to ONLY display "john doe2" (where is the "filter"?)

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know how to "filter" it, I only know how to fully showing both of them

Comment: but it is your project, what are you requirements to do so? How does the client want that to happen? Try something and share it with us!